# python invalid syntax без причины помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python

```
class OddEvenSeparator():

    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def add_number(self, number):
        self.lst.append(number)

    def even(self):
        return list(filter(lambda x / x % 2 == 0, self.lst))

    def odd(self):
        return list(filter(lambda x / x % 2 != 0, self.lst))
```

10:37 invalid syntax
help

Comment: Без причины? Вы считаете, создатели языка врут? А где конкретно возникает ошибка мы сами должны догадаться?

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `lambda` записывается следующим образом:

```
lambda <формальные параметры (аргументы)> : <возвращаемое значение>
```

Пример lambda-выражения:

```
a = lambda x, y: x**2 + 2*x*y + y**2
```

Ключевое слово `lambda` без двоеточия действительно является синтаксической ошибкой.